# What is the use of drop_first in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What exactly is the use of `drop_first=True` in the code below?

```
ins = pd.get_dummies(ins, columns=['gender', 'region'], drop_first=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for including the `drop_first` when using this function is to avoid creating a multicollinearity issue between the variables, this means that after using the `get_dummies()` function a regression model might find a linear relationship between them, hence not fulfilling the Guass-Markov theorem for linear regression, leading to errors and OLS not being BLUE.

This is a coding issue indeed, but the explination is more statistics / data science / cross validation oriented. So I would recommend checking this answer and/or asking there aswell: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224051/one-hot-vs-dummy-encoding-in-scikit-learn/224055#224055

Comment: I was putting together a good example of this.  But this is spot on.

Comment: Cheers! Fun fact, my thesis was about Gauss-Markov theorem!